# Access Query Params in view or in view's controller

Tags: ember.js

so in the users/confirmation route, I am able to access that confirmation_token in the setupController hook

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(PresentsModalsMixin, {
   setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    controller.get('confirmation_token'); // token I want in query params is available here.
   }
});
```

but in the view the confirmation token is no longer at `this.get('controller.confirmation_token'')`

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
     templateName: 'users/confirmation',

    actions: {
      submit: function() {
        this.get('controller.confirmation_token'); // null
        this.get('controller').send('submit');
      }
   }
}   
});
```

in the controller where the action goes, it is also no longer available

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ["confirmation_token"],
  confirmation_token: null,

  actions: {
   submit: function() {
    this.get('confirmation_token'); // null value
   }
  }
});
```

why is the query param getting blown away? and is there a way I can get it back

the template that is calling the view looks like this

`{{render 'users/confirmation' currentUser}}`

Comment: Are you sure that, when you're trying to access `confirmation_token` in Controller submit action and in the view, queryParam confirmation_token is still present in URL?

Comment: yeah it's still there, a hack I can do is this.controllerFor('application').set('confirmationToken', controller.get('confirmation_token')); in the setupController method of the route then access that in the controller in my submit action to use it, there must be a better solution

Comment: Is it a typo in your question, or is it also in your code? `this.get('controller.confirmation_token''); // null` shouldn't be `this.get('controller.confirmation_token'); // null`. Notice a single quotation mark.

Comment: sorry typo in my question, I inspected this.get('controller') in the chrome devtools and the confirmation_token is completely blown away, i can view the key by doing this.get('controller.queryParams') which returns me an array of the keys of the controller's queryParams but between the route setup and the view initialization, the query param value gets blown away even though its still in my url

Comment: okay I think i found the solution, removing currentUser and not passing a second argument fixes this and allows me to retrieve it in both view and controller

Comment: Maybe new controller is being generated because of `setupController` method being called with another model? Anyway, please add your answer to this question and mark it as accepted, because you solved that.

Comment: okay it says I can mark it as accepted in 2 days or can you mark it for me?

Comment: No, I can't. You're the person who asks question - and only you can mark it as accepted if answer is helpful for you(solved your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct answer is

```
{{render 'users/confirmation'}}
```

removing currentUser as the second argument and not passing any argument fixes this issue and allows you to keep the query params, it gets overwritten when you pass a second argument like this

```
{{render 'users/confirmation' currentUser}}
```